# How can I find the most items of a certain type in a List?

Tags: c#, string, linq, list

Given a `List<string>` with the following elements: `1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, ?, , 4, A, 1, 7, 1, 9, 3`

What is a good way to find the number that occurs the most, that excludes `null` values and non-numerics? LINQ is okay (I know it's not always very efficient, but it is fun. :) ).

Comment: Linq can be just as efficient (and sometimes more efficient) than loops you write yourself.

Comment: what have you tried?  nothing?  the linq things you need are Where, groupby, and count

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
var numericPattern = new Regex(@"^-?\d+$");
var result = list.Where(x => x != null && numericPattern.Matches(x))
                 .GroupBy(x => x, (key, group) => new { Value = key, 
                                                        Count = group.Count() } )
                 .OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Count)
                 .First();
```

Note that instead of `OrderByDescending` you could use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com)'s `MaxBy` operator:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x != null && digitsOnly.Matches(x))
                 .GroupBy(x => x, (key, group) => new { Value = key, 
                                                        Count = group.Count() } )
                 .MaxBy(pair => pair.Count);
```

Either way, the result will have the value and the number of times it occurred.

(Also note that this will include numbers which are too big to store in an `int` - if you want to perform actual parsing, you should do that instead.)

Comment: Hm... what if there are two numbers that occur at the same frequency? Is there a way to account for that? What happens if you input `1, 1, 2, 2`?

Comment: @SpikeX: It will give you whichever comes first, I believe.

Comment: Your GroupBy clause is returning an error... it wants a `delegate` as the second parameter of the `GroupBy()` method. -- *Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type.*

Comment: Ah, nevermind... it should be `Value = group,` not `Value = group.Key,`. Fixed it. :)

Comment: @SpikeX: Hmmm - it shouldn't have been `Value = group`. I had some slightly different problems, but hopefully I've fixed that now.

Comment: Oh, also, `Matches(x)` should be `IsMatch(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

you're looking for the "Mode" (the value that occurs most often) right?

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/05/07/linq-mean-median-and-mode.aspx

```
var mode = numbers.GroupBy(n=> n). 
    OrderByDescending(g=> g.Count()). 
    Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault(); 
Debug.WriteLine(("Mode is: " + mode));
```

Comment: just need a where to filter out the numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
int mostFrequent = elements.Where(s => s != null)
    .Select(s => {
        int i;
        bool isValid = int.TryParse(s, out i);
        return new { IsValid = isValid, Value = i }
    })
    .Where(v => v.IsValid)
    .GroupBy(i => i.Value)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .First().Key
```